Add caller information with Opentelemetry java agent instrumentation
I have test java app with java agent opentelemetry instrumentation: -javaagent:/usr/src/app/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-context-data.enabled=true -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-appender.enabled=true -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-appender.experimental.capture-mdc-attributes=*
And I have logs:
{
  "resourceLogs" : [
    {
      "resource" : {
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "key" : "container.id",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "97dc4496d3a0573ca8264184162c7870122daa52aba1d8d76578ee93135f31eb"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "host.arch",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "amd64"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "host.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "97dc4496d3a0"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "k8s.namespace.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "name-space"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "os.description",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "Linux 5.15.150.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "os.type",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "linux"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.command_line",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -javaagent:/usr/src/app/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-context-data.enabled=true -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-appender.enabled=true -Dotel.instrumentation.log4j-appender.experimental.capture-mdc-attributes=* oteldemo.Service"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.executable.path",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.pid",
            "value" : {
              "intValue" : "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.runtime.description",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.0.4+7-LTS"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.runtime.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "OpenJDK Runtime Environment"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "process.runtime.version",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "21.0.4+7-LTS"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "service.instance.id",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "1a4d8792-2b25-4524-ab33-4d1029939db8"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "service.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "service"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "telemetry.distro.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "opentelemetry-java-instrumentation"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "telemetry.distro.version",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "2.3.0"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "telemetry.sdk.language",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "java"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "telemetry.sdk.name",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "opentelemetry"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "telemetry.sdk.version",
            "value" : {
              "stringValue" : "1.37.0"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "scopeLogs" : [
        {
          "scope" : {
            "name" : "oteldemo.Service"
          },
          "logRecords" : [
            {
              "timeUnixNano" : "1727765793069162445",
              "observedTimeUnixNano" : "1727765793069195376",
              "severityNumber" : 9,
              "severityText" : "INFO",
              "body" : {
                "stringValue" : "Service starting."
              },
              "attributes" : [
              ],
              "traceId" : "",
              "spanId" : ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "schemaUrl" : "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.24.0"
    }
  ]
}

I need to add to log fields callerClass, callerLine, threadName and others which I can insert to the log4j appender using JsonTemplateLayout, for example:
"threadName": {
    "$resolver": "thread",
    "field": "name"
},
"callerClass": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "className"
},
"callerMethod": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "methodName"
},
"callerLine": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "lineNumber"
}

How to do the same using Java agent OpenTelemetry instrumentation (embedded OpenTelemetry appender)?

this is implemented for logback (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-appender-1.0/javaagent#settings-for-the-logback-appender-instrumentation) but not for log4j yet if you want to open an issue or contribute this feature
